# Adding Arraylist values method java

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

I want to create a method to add the Arraylist firstRow. But I keep getting the error nullPointerexception. Its because of the for loop `for(int i = 0; i<firstRow.length; i++)` in the `getArraylistsum()` method

Here is the whole code:

```
int[] row1;

public int getArraylistsum(){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<row1.length; i++){
        sum += row1.length;
    }
    return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<Integer> row1 = new Arraylist<>(10); 
    row1.add(1);
    row1.add(8);
    row1.add(6);

    ClassName row = new ClassName(); 
    System.out.println(row.getArraylistsum());

}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perhaps you could write something like `int[] row1 = new int[10];` on your first line - actually make the array instead of just declaring it.  Also, it's a really bad idea to use the same name for that array as you've used for the `ArrayList` that you created inside `main`.

Comment: @DavidWallace I guess the value of row1 never passed to getArraylistsum function

Comment: @KickButtowski I imagine that will be the general gist of Supernatural's next question on this site.

Comment: @DavidWallace another issue is the op is using arraylist in the main and array in the function. so how the op wants to match the size of arraylist to array ? god knows

Comment: @DavidWallace cannot stop laughing bc of ur comments :D :'( :D

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialize

```
  int[] row1;// when you create a instance of a class this row1 will null
```

Then `row1.length` give you `NullPointerException`

You need to initialize `row1` before use it.

```
 int[] row1=new int[size];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think int[] row1 is not necessary and values is not assigned to row1 array too. rather than used row1 array, passed the row1 arraylist to your method. In the main function, ArrayList is written as Arraylist. I changed this into Arraylist.

```
 public int getArraylistsum(ArrayList<Integer> row1){

    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<row1.size(); i++){
        sum += row1.get(i);
    }
    return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<Integer> row1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(10); 
    row1.add(1);
    row1.add(8);
    row1.add(6);

    ClassName row = new ClassName(); 
    System.out.println(row.getArraylistsum(row1));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<Integer> row1` is declared and initialized in your main method. Your `getArraylistsum()` tries to access a different `int[] row1` variable which in not initialized. Therefore it causes a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

First initialize row1

```
int[] row1;
```

In your case as row1 is not intialized and you are trying to acces the length of that row1 thats why you received `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

You are using two `row1` variables.
Make the ArrayList variable a static class variable by declaring the List by `static ArrayList<Integer> row1;` instead of the `int[]`.
In the Main Method you then should use `ClassName.row1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();`.

Answer (score 0):

`null.length` definitely gives you `NullPointerException`
`int[] row1 = null;` and you are calling method on `null` instance inside `getArraylistsum()` method.

initialize row1 instance inside your getArraylistsum() method using below code.

> row1=new int[size];

Answer (score 0):

You should use for each function like

```
public int getArraylistsum(ArrayList<Integer> row1){

    int sum = 0;
    for(int i:row1){
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```